# getWidth and getHeight methods aren't functioning properly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a line to terminate my script if a given range includes more than one cell. However, when a multi-cell range is passed in, my conditional statement does not trigger.

I went ahead and used the logger to see what was returning with these methods.

```
Logger.log("Width: " + range.getWidth);
Logger.log("Height: " + range.getHeight);
if((range.getWidth > 1) || (range.getHeight > 1)) return;
```

The range variable has a 35-row and 1-column range, so getHeight should give me 35, and the conditional should be triggered. However, this is what's showing in the logs:

> [19-08-18 15:37:17:179 EDT] Width: function getWidth() {/*
>   */}
>
> [19-08-18 15:37:17:180 EDT] Height: function getHeight() {/*
>   */}

It looks like the Google functions are commented out. These methods are supposed to return an integer. Is this a known current bug with Google Apps Script or am I just doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried **calling** the methods? As any other method, calls are usually made with `(parameter list if accepts parameters)`. E.g. `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`

Comment: @TheMaster 's answer is the correct way to deal with your situation, you should also take a look at [these examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) on using the APIs and App Scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the `Logger`, `range.getWidth` is a function. You're getting a function, but not running/calling it. `getWidth` function  should be executed to give width as a result.

```
range.getWidth();
```